# Form is not submitting/Working

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

This form Submission is not working, Can anyone help me...

> I am using bootstrap css and trying to submit a simple form, there is a small issue but I can't detect the problem, please help

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="thumbs askus container col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
        <form id="logfrm" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" name="unm" class="form-control" id="inputUser" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
              <button class="btn btn-default" >Sign in</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP Code for form handling

```
if (isset($_POST['unm'])) {
if ($_POST['unm']=="admin" && $_POST['pwd']=="xxxxxx") {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Hi Admin");</script>';
    header('Location: home.php');
}
else{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Unknown Username/Bad password");</script>';
}
```

}

Comment: Well what doesn't work?

Comment: The "action" field in the form tag is empty. Put there your PHP script address.

Comment: action="" same page?

Comment: @ojovirtual if it is empty then he wants it to load in the same page

Comment: Yes, PHP script is on d same page

Comment: can you try it? <input type="submit" /> instead <button type="submit"

Comment: I've tried it... but not working

Comment: what error you are getting? can you echo something after this line? if (isset($_POST['unm'])) {

Comment: No error... the page is refreshed when submit button pressed, I've tried echo $_POST['unm']; (inside & outside of if stmnt) but no data is set for $_POST['unm']

Comment: Why their is a downvote for my Answer?? PLease try the answer and comment your needs if it not a solution you are expecting.

Comment: @AjeshVC: The `action` attribute is not necessary – every relevant browser out there will simply submit a form to the current address if it is not set or empty.

Answer (score 1):

If your php for this form is on the same page, then it would make sense to direct the action to the same page. That way, the form will be sent to a refreshed version of the page where the PHP will pick it up and process it from there.

so - if you form is on a page called form.php

then it should be

```
<form id="logfrm" action="form.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

You can monitor the $_POST['umn'] using Firebug to see that everything is send properly

Comment: I've already tried that,the page is not navigated to other page on d submission

Comment: the order of the php on the page is important - when the form resubmits to the same page it will run the scripts from the top of the page down, so it may be an issue of positioning of the php on the page - where is the php on the same page?

Answer (score -1):

You just missed the action url so that the form submission does not working ... I just change the form action tag from **action=""** to **action="action.php"** where **action.php** is the file containing your php codes to handle the html form.Use the below Code this will solve your problem.

home.php

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_button']))
    {

if ($_POST['unm']=="admin" && $_POST['pwd']=="xxxxxx") {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Ok");</script>';
    header('Location:home.php');
}
else{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Unknown Username/Bad password"); if(confirm("Unknown Username/Bad password")){document.location.reload(true);}</script>';

}
}

else
{

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="thumbs askus container col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
        <form id="logfrm"  method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="home.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" name="unm" class="form-control" id="inputUser" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit_button" >Sign in</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  <?php } ?>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm submitting d form to same page

Comment: problem resolved... bt I don't get d actual trouble making cause, anyway it is solved

Comment: @SarathMohan Please comment your actual problem? i think for the above question, this should be the solution.